# Tasker Android - Repeatedly keep volume high when headphones plugged in

Tags: android, tasker

Android now has the annoying 'feature' of turning down my volume when AUX is plugged in, thinking I'm using headphones.

I'm looking at Tasker to keep the volume raised up in Kodi.  Here's what happens.

```
1 - Kodi Opens
2- Tasker profile on Kodi raises volume two clicks below max.
```

Now a song can play, and finish.. Google detects this and turns DOWN my music (way to harsh the vibes guys)..

How can I repeatedly turn up the volume? or hold the volume? with Tasker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Far, the best I could do is

```
check every 1 minute
   if (volume is too low) {
       //turn up volume 
   }
```

And then reference the initial task of opening KODI itself on exit